# Why is the meteor shell not giving me a return value for this function call?

Tags: meteor

For this particular function call, I'm not seeing any return values. I want to know what the return value is so I can determine whether a record was found or not.

```
> Rooms.findOne({name: "this record doesn't exist"})
> null //me entering 'null' manually
null
> []
[]
> "test"
'test'
> Rooms.findOne({name: "this record doesn't exist either"})
>
```

Comment: what did you get with `Rooms.findOne({},{name: "this record doesn't exist"})`

Comment: nothing, no return value, just another prompt that follows.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but try `x = rooms.findone` and then type x to see its value.

Comment: This is the result I get: https://gist.github.com/brlafreniere/53274d047cf8f366e400

Answer (score 0):

Trying with `typeof` gives:

```
> typeof Rooms.findOne({name: "this record doesn't exist"})
> 'undefined'
```

Which means meteor server-shell somehow does not return `undefined`! looking into source code it could be caused here https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/release-1.1/tools/server/shell-server.js#L253